# Replaced HDD but screen wont turn on

Tags: hard-drive

I had a SMART error (301) on my hard drive which required the hdd to be replaced.

The computer is a HP Mini Netbook 110-3135DX. I already have a usb installer ready to make the OS installation.  Tried booting up with and without the usb plugged in, still not working.

So after I replaced the HDD, I try to boot but the screen wont turn on. What can be the problem?

Comment: Does the screen say anything when you try to turn it on?

Comment: Nothing..I can hear the computer working but I just get a black screen.

Comment: As I said before, it is a netbook

Comment: Already tried that, still no response

Comment: It's not the display because I placed the old HDD and the error keeps coming up on screen. There is a system diagnostics option I can access but it only confirms that the HDD is not working and that it needs to be replaced.

Comment: ...So you get errors with the old HDD and nothing with the old one?

Comment: Nothing with the NEW* one, yep

Answer (score 0):

BIOS wasn't even loading on power. I ended up removing the CMOS battery (to reset BIOS) and powering the computer without it. That did the trick.